# AWS pricing and usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to use AWS. I have a $20 gift card, and I am currently running c4.8xlarge 36 132 60 EBS Only $1.993 per Hour.

On the AWS webpage, it says c4.8xlarge, status: running.

I am currently connecting to it through mac terminal (ssh).

Question:

1) if I disconnect my ssh, do I still being charge $?

2) if I disconnect (by clicking AWS -> state ->stop), and then turn it back on, where will be data go?

3) I am running the vm through terminal (ssh) on mac book. If I close my macbook (close the lip, put it onto sleep mode), and when I turn it back on, does the VM still running at the background?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you disconnect ssh, you will still be charged
2. Unless you terminate the vm, the data will remain in the vm
3. If your laptop goes to sleep mode, vm still will be on. But if you are running a server through command line, then you need to manage those servers with process managers.

For example, if you are running node server by using

```
node .
```

Then when your laptop goes to sleep, the server will be stopped.

If you use process manager like pm2, then it will keep running in background.

Regarding your question in comment

> When you stop an instance, we shut it down. We don't charge hourly usage for a stopped instance, or data transfer fees, but we do charge for the storage for any Amazon EBS volumes. Each time you start a stopped instance we charge a full instance hour, even if you make this transition multiple times within a single hour.

Source : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html

Comment: how do I stop the vm (not being charge) AND let the data remain on the machine?

Comment: As per the source, you will be charged for ebs volume storage when you shut down vm

Answer (score 0):

There are two charges associated with your Amazon EC2 instance:

- An hourly charge based on the Instance Type
- A charge for the Amazon EBS disk volumes

(There are some other charges, such as Data Transfer, but they will likely be negligible compared to the above.)

The **hourly charge** only applies while the instance is *Running*. While the instance is running, you will be charged -- regardless of whether you are connected to the instance.

You can **Stop** your instance to stop this hourly charge. It's just like using the Shutdown command on a PC -- the computer turns off but any data stored on the disk will still be there when you Start it again.

The **charge for the EBS disk volumes** is "per GB per month, pro rata" so it will continue to be charged even when your instance is Stopped, because you want the data to be there when you Start it again.

When you are totally finished using the instance, you can **Terminate** the instance, which does a Stop and then deletes both the instance and the attached disks (although this behavior is configurable). Therefore, you won't be charged anything once the instance is terminated.

By the way, a `c4.8xlarge` is a rather powerful instance (36 vCPUs, 60GB RAM) -- you might consider using a smaller instance if you wish to reduce costs. Very few use-cases need such a powerful computer.

Answer (score 0):

1) You will be chargeable however your disconnecting from the server. Because you're just disconnecting from the server but not stopping or terminating the server. For your information even if your stopping the instance you will be chargeable for the EBS volume which attached in the machine(instance EC2).

- AWS will charege your instance in Hourly base.
- Make sure your EBS volume attached to the instance makred flag as Delete on Termination. If No you have to delete the EBS volume after terminated the instance. If your forgot to delete the EBS volume then AWS will charege your EBS volume storage.

2) There are two kinds of storage in EC2 instance, one is Instance Storage(ephemeral) and the other one is EBS volume which attached in Your instance(EC2).

*So Whenever your stop the instance your data will be losted. if the data in Ephemeral but not it EBS.

3) If your meaning VM is (Instance EC2). Then the Answer is yes. your ssh Will be disconnected from the Server but the Instance Will be in Running state then you will be chargeable.

Let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks